# How to remove SKU column from Invoice pdf. Magento Version 1.9.x

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.9

How can i remove the sku column from Magento invoice PDF? and i tried to make some changes which those files but it's not working for me.

app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php to 
app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php

app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Default.php to 
app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Default.php

app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php to 
app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DO following changes:
1)
Copy

**app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php**

To

**app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php**

And in Invoice.php (of local directory)
remove following code

```
$lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('SKU'),
            'feed'  => 290,
            'align' => 'right'
        );
```

This will remove title of sku from table in PDF

2)
Copy

**app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Default.php**

To

**app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Default.php**

And in Default.php (of local directory)
remove following code

```
$lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($this->getSku($item), 17),
            'feed'  => 290,
            'align' => 'right'
        );
```

This will remove sku data

Now print your Invoice